# Can any one experience the World without a language? if yes to what extent, if no, why not?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, cognitive-linguistics, sapir-whorf-hypothesis

I am exploring of a possibility of experiencing the world around without a language. By listening, speaking, seeing and reflecting on words made by the alphabets of a language - one experiences the World. How far is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Don't do it! It will be a huge disappointment, however attractive the prospect may seem.

Comment: @Alenanno - Language is tool every one has to learn to experience and share what one experiences in the world around. On one hand language is a bias, a limit to experience the world , on the other hand without language one can't even experience the world at all, experienceable can be shared through a common language. So, what it is True experience of the world without the language? Is it shareable ? If yes how - ? So any communication- verbal , non- verbal that requires any kind of language including sign- in the absence of that , what is the experience of world ? And how can that be shared?

Comment: @CharanSingh Can you take this explanation and reword your question including it? It'd be more clear (admitting there are others like me). :)

Comment: @Cerberus- I m convinced there should be a relation between the language one uses as a tool to experience the world and what is before that language that prepares one to experience and makes one capable to share the experiences as well. Further this relationship/ bridge/ connection between the language - and what is before the language should be objectively measurable. Please elaborate more on likely disappoints; much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not clear whether you are using the word _alphabets_ literally or metaphorically. If you intend it literally, please note that many people in the world today and in the past, and all small children, have experienced the world without _written_ language.

Comment: There are a small number of cases of children being found who lacked anything like what we would consider 'language'. For example, the case of Genie: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genie_%28feral_child%29 These can give *some* insight into such a possibility, but it's (necessarily) rather impressionistic.

Comment: @Colin- The challenge in those experiences seems what can be termed as "Isolated Communications" - inability to share with others, objectively/reflectively measurable by others. What I am suggesting is thus alphabets as solid tools of a language that are reflective, providing objective measurements. Having known/learnt a language (say ,as an adult) what are the possibilities of going back into baby state of mind - exploring /experiencing what was experienced before the language was learnt  - and since the tools of language are learnt - reverting to use these tools to share those experiences.

Comment: @LaurenG- What will be interesting to explore seems not from the language acquisition perspective, but exploring the possibilities from normal human beings who have learnt the language, thus acquired the skill , to use the skill on one hand and reflect back ( reminiscence) what was there before the language was learnt and, on the other hand,share with others since the language is learnt now - What were the experiences when language was not learnt/without language.

Comment: @Alenanno - Please count me in ( "admitting there are other like me";)) Here is another way to look at - I learnt about myself from others, using a language ( with Universal Characteristics : listening, speaking, seeing, reflecting). Example - I was told/I learnt this and I remembered that I was born like this, this, at this place, at this time...and so on. Now that I know the language tool - Can I go back and experience what was it like, Who I was,before I learnt the language, and share with others what experiences were without the language was learnt.;)

Comment: What you are asking is interesting. But in using "alphabet" you are conveying the impression that you know next to nothing about language. An alphabet is a tool with which we can do languagey things, but it is no more a tool of language than is a tape recorder.

Comment: @CharanSingh I just noticed that you [cross-posted this in Philosophy.SE](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/can-any-one-experience-the-world-without-a-language-if-yes-to-what-extent-if-n) as well (actually, I saw the Philosophy post first). It is my understanding that StackExchange frowns upon duplicate posts across the sites.

Comment: @CharanSingh - In that case, you probably want to look at the cases of children born deaf who don't have exposure to language until quite late: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_period_hypothesis#Deaf_and_feral_children some of these children go on to learn language and can recollect their pre-linguist life, although often they find it hard to articulate what it was like. This was part of the syllabus of a course I sat in on for Language Acquisition, but I don't recall any of the specific literature.

Comment: I would advice you to read Chomsky's On the nature and language and the science of language. He argues that language is an instinct such as to walk or to read and communication is a by product of a language. He supports it by inner language and thoughts. no metter wither person deaf or not, s/he will always talk to himself/ herself inside. Thus, according to him it is impossible to live without a language. (note that language and communication two different things)

Comment: @ all- thankyou so much. Please allow me to share following link to a related conversation http://www.ted.com/conversations/16464/after_learning_a_language_why.html    I have provide link to our conversation at Ted also.

Comment: @Colin - Your very right, I - "know next to nothing about language" Language is my love, reason and passion to find a meaning of this life and I m not a linguist. @ Denis - Pardon me -being new to this forum, cross posting was unintentional- I will stick with this thread - unless some deeper language inquiries make connections in philosophy thread.

Answer (score 3):

[Genie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genie_%28feral_child%29) was a feral child who was abused and grew up almost without linguistic skills but acquired some language skills as a teenager. The papers published on her case might provide insights into the view point of someone who does not have language.

Answer (score 0):

As a speech-language therapist (M.S., CCC-SLP), I have met people who obviously perceive the world and who just as obviously lack language.

During my training, I worked briefly with someone with global aphasia.   Thanks to certain brain injuries, such as strokes, some people wind up with aphasia, or loss of some of their language abilities.   The most severe form of aphasia, namely total loss of the ability to communicate with conventional (i.e. arbitrary) symbols, is called global aphasia.   See this Wikipedia article on global aphasia:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_aphasia

Global aphasia differs from dementia in that global aphasia patients can do well on non-verbal IQ tests and on many tasks that do not require symbol use, whereas the victims of severe dementia score low on tests of language and cognition and have difficulty doing most tasks.

Strokes and brain injuries arent' the only conditions that can manifest themselves in the lack of language.   Over the last ten years or so, I have worked with increasing numbers of students whose autism is so severe that they have not acquired an L1, and must be taught to communicate with picture exchange.

caseyr547 has already mentioned Genie.  You may wish to read the book "Genie, a Scientific Tragedy" by Russ Rymer.   Her case is instructive, but one need not look at such rare cases to document perception without language.